# How to remove the empty td tags using coldfusion regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to remove the empty `td` elements from the html page, those `td` elements have some space in them but they are empty.

I tried following two techniques, but both didn't work for me.

```
<cfset data= Replace(data,'<td></td>','','all')>

<cfset data= ReReplace(data,'<\w+[^>]*(/>|>\s*?</\w+>)','','all')>
```

Another Thing: I have many `th` elements, how can i write some kind of logic to keep the first encountered `TH` and remove the all others including the `tr` in which they will be defined

Comment: From where is the html page coming?

Comment: i had saved the page on my system and reading it

Comment: If this is a one time thing, it might be quicker to do it manually.

Comment: but it is not one time, if that is the case, i could have manipulated myself before posting a question

Comment: In that case, I suggest taking things one step at a time.  You posted two tags and a very vague statement of did not work.  What actually happened with each tag?

Comment: let's work on first one, if u find second statement, you ignore it

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-parsing-traversing-and-mutating-html-with-coldfusion-and-jsoup.htm

Comment: i do mistake asking questions here, jsoup, damm

Answer (score 0):

To remove a `<td>` tag and closing tag with space in between, using regex, should be as simple as:

```
<cfset mydata = REReplace(mydata, "<td\b[^>]*>\s*<\/td>", "", "All") />
```

I'm asserting a word boundary above to avoid replacing any tags that start with `td` but aren't `<td>` tags (although I can't think of any).

Your second attempt (with the `\w` character class) would remove a lot more than `<td>` tags!